# String Parsing from eBird website in r

Tags: html, r, xml, parsing

I've been trying to figure out string parsing, but seem to be in over my head. I want my final product to be a character vector of the the "Species Name" column from [this webpage.](http://ebird.org/ebird/country/CR?yr=all)
So far, I have at something like this:

```
url <- 'http://ebird.org/ebird/country/CR?yr=all'
doc <- htmlParse(rawToChar(GET(url)$content))
string <- as(doc, "character")
```

I have found that the species names occur here (in this case, White-bellied Storm-Petrel):

```
<td headers="s" class="species-name">White-bellied Storm-Petrel</td>
```

How might I be able to pull all of these and collect them into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `rvest`

```
library(rvest)
species <- read_html(url) %>%
              html_nodes('td.species-name') %>%
              html_text
head(species)
#[1] "Common Pauraque"           "Roadside Hawk"             "Inca Dove"
#[4] "Common Ground-Dove"        "White-winged Dove"        
#[6] "Rufous-tailed Hummingbird"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!